# Close the application before the form loads

Tags: c#

I have a program wherein I will check if a file exists. If it does, the form will load. But if not, a messagebox will appear to inform the user, and then the application needs to close without showing the form.

How do I do this properly? I tried using this code on the constructor:

```
    Environment.Exit(-1);
```

It does what I want, but from what I've read it's not a good way to do it. Is this correct? Or shall I just go with using the above code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need to call anything if you put your check before the application run of the main form

```
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        // Check for file 
        if(!File.Exists("your file to check"))             
        {
            MessageBox.Show(.....)
        }
        else
        {
            Application.Run(new frmMain());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Oh yes. I seem to have overlooked that solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
yourForm.close();
```

Or just don't call the form until you are sure that the file doesn't exist.

If you have other processes running you can call a method to close them all rather than have it with out cluttering up your main code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: somewhat simpler (I think, I have understood you correctly)

```
if (File.Exists("somefile.txt"))
{
   //do your operation
}
else
{
    this.Close();
}
```